# Convert cell from text to value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I extrapolated a file in extension .xlsx
and I import in Google Sheets
but the value is in text format but I need in value format
How could I change the format with a script ?

value in text format ( I know because if i do `=isnumber()` the result is "false" )

i do this

```
for (var y=0; y< lastRow ; y++){
    Cronistoria.getRange(y,21);
    Cronistoria.getCurrentCell(y,21).setFormula('=value()');
```

there are a word for example "parseInt"? or other?

Comment: Try setNumberFormat("0.##############");

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script uses JavaScript as programming language.

- A Google Sheets "text", in JavaScript is a string.
- A Google Sheets "value", in JavaScript is a number.

In JavaScript, to convert a string into a number you could use [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), i.e. `Number('1.3')` returns `1.3`,  `parseInt('1.3')` returns `1`.